# creating default object from empty value in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to make two functions in controller that have post action and that are in the same page.
My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $status = DB::table('analytics')->where('dienstleistung', '!=', '')->get();
    //Save data
        $rules = [          
        'site_id'       => 'required',
        'dienstleistung'        => 'required',
        'objekt'        => 'required',
        'zimmer'        => 'required',
        'vorname'       => 'required',
        'name'      => 'required',
        'strasse'       => 'required',
        'ort'       => 'required',
        'plz'       => 'required',
        'tel'       => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'reinigungstermin'      => 'required',
        'gekommen'      => 'required',
        'message'       => 'required',
        'status'        => 'required',
        'answer'        => 'required',
        'notiz'         => 'required',
        'userId'        => 'required',
                ];

                $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

                if($validator->fails()) {
                    return Redirect::to('anfrage')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
                }
                else {
                    $anfrage = new Analytic();                      
                    $anfrage->site_id = Input::get('site_id');
                    $anfrage->dienstleistung = Input::get('dienstleistung');
                    $anfrage->objekt = Input::get('objekt');
                    $anfrage->zimmer = Input::get('zimmer');
                    $anfrage->vorname = Input::get('vorname');
                    $anfrage->name = Input::get('name');
                    $anfrage->strasse = Input::get('strasse');
                    $anfrage->ort = Input::get('ort');
                    $anfrage->plz = Input::get('plz');
                    $anfrage->tel = Input::get('tel');
                    $anfrage->email = Input::get('email');
                    $anfrage->reinigungstermin = Input::get('reinigungstermin');
                    $anfrage->gekommen = Input::get('gekommen');
                    $anfrage->message = Input::get('message');
                    $anfrage->status = Input::get('status');
                    $anfrage->answer = Input::get('answer');
                    $anfrage->notiz = Input::get('notiz');
                    $anfrage->userId = Input::get('userId');
                    try {

                        $anfrage->save();
                        flash()->success(trans('app.success'));
                        return Redirect::to('anfrage');

                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        Log::writeException($e);
                        return Redirect::to('anfrage')
                            ->withErrors($e->getMessage())
                            ->withInput();
                    }

                }

}
 public function editItem(Request $request) {
    $anfrages = Analytic::find($request['id']  );

        $anfrages->status = $request->status;
    $anfrages->answer = $request->answer;
    $anfrages->notiz = $request->notiz;
     $anfrages->save();
    return response ()->json( $anfrages );
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('anfrage', 'AnfrageController@store');
Route::post ( 'anfrage', 'AnfrageController@editItem' );
```

EditItem function is OK, it makes changes when I want to edit data, but when I want to store data, message being displayed is:
**creating default object from empty value**
So, I need to leave active only one of these function, both are not working.

Comment: You have written same route for two function, obviously `editItem` going to get hit every time (even if you meant for `store`)

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I must write same route because both of functions are in the same blade and both of them are POST method , how can I write a  different route?

Comment: You need clear your concepts about route controller and blade or MVC. Your route has nothing to do with blade. You are trying to hit one URL and expect it to execute 2 different functions..

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by changing url name.